# Apache POI JDK version

Tags: java, ant, apache-poi

I was looking for examples on how to create an XML File in ANT for Java project using Apache POI library. I encountered this statement:

> POI 3.5 and later requires the JDK version 1.5 or later. Versions prior to 3.5 require JDK 1.4+ [here](http://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html)

I am using Apache 3.9 and set the JDK of my project to Java 1.4 and I didn't encounter any error when trying to run my program via eclipse. But my question is if I make build.xml in ANT and deploy the JAR file. Will my project still run<sup>(3)</sup>?

### Extra info

1. I created a build.xml using the ANT plugin in eclipse then Run as --> Ant Build. I didn't encounter any error.
2. Also set the JRE to JDK1.4
3. I haven't tested this yet if it runs or not because I still don't know how to add a JAR configuration in build.xml... I am still learning how to use ANT.

Comment: *"I am still learning how to use ANT."*  The most relevant parts of Ant have task names that map well to the JDK equivalents.  See the [Task List](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasklist.html) for potentials.

Comment: Hi thanks for the link Andrew!

Comment: You're welcome.  Unfortunately the set of pages is (badly) frames based.  The best way into it is http://ant.apache.org/manual/ (then it is 2 clicks to get hat list 1) Ant Tasks 2) List of tasks.  -- Or right, the I just also saw what I'd really liked to link before **[Overview of Ant Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html)**  Which is a list and *description* of tasks.

Comment: THe overview of ant tasks link is a bit better its quite comprehensive though. I'll just reference this from time to time. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

If the project states that JDK 1.5 or higher is required it means that usually no testing is done with lower versions. It might still work (to some degree) as you found out, but likely will stop working with newer version of Apache POI.

Comment: The JDK version is only ever updated when a feature requires it, so at least something will always break! Quite possibly most things...