# Workarounds for using apache poi 3.9 with JDK 4

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352638/java-program-using-apache-poi-3-9-encountered-error-in-xml-build-file) . I just found this caption in [Apache POI website](http://poi.apache.org/).

> POI 3.5 and later requires the JDK version 1.5 or later. Versions prior to 3.5 require JDK 1.4+

Clearly, that's the reason I can't build my Java program. I would just like to know if there are any workarounds where I can successfully build my project in Ant using my current settings.

#### Settings

- Apache POI - 3.9
- JDK - 1.4.2 (4.0)

Any advice, tips, or hacks are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi dimas, why you can't move to newer version of JDK?

Comment: Because its the current JDK the company uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 1.4 is pretty old now - it was released in 2002 so over 10 years ago. Regular support ended in 2008, so I dread to think how much you're having to pay Oracle for extended support for it... If possible divert some of that cash to an upgrade project!

The last version of [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to run on Java 1.4 was POI 3.2, released in October 2008. Source and binary packages of it are available from [the Apache dist archive](http://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/). There are two main snags with using POI 3.2 today, the first is that it only supports the binary file formats. It does not support the OOXML formats such as .xlsx, .pptx, .docx. Support for those (via XSLF, XSSF and XWPF) was only introduced with POI 3.5, and required the bump to Java 5 as the minimum. The second issue is you'll be missing out on [5 years of bug fixes and new features](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), of which there have been a lot!

It's been a few years since anyone asked about newer versions of Apache POI on old JDKs (everyone else has managed to upgrade to something with normal support available!). When people were asking, a common answer was to try [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/), which should let you load and run JDK 5 code on JDK 1.4. I've not tried it myself, but people given that answer seemed to be happy so I assume it'll do the trick...

(Converting POI 3.9 to run on JDK 1.4 would be a lot of work for you. Since the 3.2 days, most of the new code has used generics, lots of old code has been greatly tidied up and simplified by moving to generics, I think there's the odd bit of varags, something about date formatters rings a bell, and there's all the XML stuff. It could be done, but it won't be quick)

Comment: I tried applying Retroweaver together with POI about 2-3 years ago but I was never able to get it to work. It could be that he is working for some SAP shop that only has Netweaver 7.0x installed. This only runs on Java 1.4 and is still supported by SAP.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Gagravarr, I have no control over upgrading java versions to newer ones its owned by the company. The only thing I can do probably is to use retroweaver, Jbossretro or retrotranslator... whichever works... lots of work indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is very difficult. Just take an example=> suppose `POI 3.9` is using feature of `Generics` or `varargs` of `jdk 1.5`, then how could you compile it with `jdk 1.4`. I suggest you either downgrade your POI version lower or upgrade your `jdk` version higher.

Edit:
Add maven dependencies add support for POI 3.2 like below code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.2-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can't upgrade my JDK version... I can downgrade my POI library but there would be alot of code changes and not to mention if poi-3.2 supports xlsx format

Comment: You are true. Seriously this is decision and design time problem. This kind of decision should be taken before beginning of project.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I actually did my research regarding this but it wasn't exhaustive enough because I failed to see this part. Anyway the project isn't that big(enterprise big). But still alot of code changes to be done. Do you know where I can download poi-3.2? I googled for it but its only one file included.

Comment: If you downgrade then there is code change and there are many risk like, whether downgraded POI will support `xlsx` format or not. If it will not support then you will have to compromise with your functionality which will add a limitation to your project. I have added maven dependencies.

Comment: I actually included that on my main question but someone edited it... well anyway thanks for pointing it out. Its one of my concerns... this problem needs a hack...

Answer (score 0):

I used [Poi 3.8 migrated to jdk 1.4](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/poi-jdk14/releases/). It works :-)