# How to read xlsx files in Java 1.4?

Tags: java, excel, xlsx, jdk1.4

I am looking for a way to read xlsx file using java 1.4, since my system java jdk can't be upgraded. I have tried several alternatives, but the libraries that I have found only support xls. Is there a library that works with jdk 1.4 and reads xlsx files with high performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot would be https://en.osdn.jp/projects/poi-jdk14/releases/ (from [Workarounds for using apache poi 3.9 with JDK 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353623/workarounds-for-using-apache-poi-3-9-with-jdk-4)) but I make no guarantees as to how well the port went, what bugs it introduced (and it *will* have introduced some!), and how well it performs, or even if it's actually what it says it is.

Given that Java 5 was released in 2004, Java 6 in 2006, and Java 1.4 was officially EOL'd in 2008, I think you're out of luck. You'd have to back-port Apache POI to 1.4 (which is what you'll find at the above link), or write the code yourself, neither of which is likely to be a lot of fun.